# GTK3 compilation won't find right GLib-2.0, which I actually compiled. What am I missing?

Tags: 16.04, compiling, libraries, gtk3, glib

The last days I struggled with libraries ([GLib2.52.2](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/general/glib2.html) & [GTK3.22.15](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/gtk3.html)), while I tried to compile them on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (fresh installation).

The **GLib2.52.2 just compiled** without errors after installing the needed dependencies.

My problem is following:

when I want to start compilation of GTK3.22.15

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-pcre=system && make -j 6
```

I get this error message:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.49.4    atk >= 2.15.1    pango >= 1.37.3    cairo >= 1.14.0    cairo-gobject >= 1.14.0    gdk-pixbuf-2.0 >= 2.30.0) were not met:

Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.49.4' but version of GLib is 2.48.2

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables BASE_DEPENDENCIES_CFLAGS
and BASE_DEPENDENCIES_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

## SOLVED EDIT

I got a suggestion to compile everything in `/usr/local` to prevent conflicts.

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-pcre=system && make -j 6
```

It did solve my problem - I didn't touch anything more, referring to the  other so said "not matching" dependencies.

> atk >= 2.15.1 ;
>   pango >= 1.37.3 ;
>   cairo >= 1.14.0 ;
>   cairo-gobject >= 1.14.0 ;
>   gdk-pixbuf-2.0 >= 2.30.0 ;

Comment: Did you `make install` the `glib-2.0` source? FWIW I'd be wary of setting `--prefix=/usr` for source-built software: IMHO it's better to stick with `/usr/local` where it's less likely to conflict with packaged software. Or use `checkinstall`.

Comment: Yes I did, forgot to mention it. But changing to the default `--prefix=/usr/local` did actually help compiling the `gtk+-3.22.15`, thanks :)